# CSS3 transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have this page here (work in progress) http://kimwilddesigns.com/index_new.htm

In this section, I want to be able to hover on the li, have the background image fade out and the h2 to fade in. Is this possible with transitions? I might not be setting it up correctly but I wanted to see if this kind of effect is even possible.

```
<div id="categories-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="fine-art"><a href="#"><img src="pics/hp_icon_fine-art.jpg" alt="fine art" width="290" height="240" border="0"></a>
            <h2>fine art work</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="gd">graphic design work</li>
        <li class="students">my students' work</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As an aside, you might want to consider adding `cursor:pointer` CSS to the little gallery arrows for next and previous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works nicely with CSS transitions, something like that:

```
#categories-wrapper li a {
    position:relative;
    display: block
}

#categories-wrapper li h2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
}

#categories-wrapper li h2,
#categories-wrapper li img {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

#categories-wrapper li:hover h2 {
    opacity: 1
}

#categories-wrapper li:hover img {
    opacity: 0
}
```

See [the Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/x9vPn/), slightly changed your markup by putting the h2 inside of the `a` tag.

Comment: You should not nest an h2 tag inside of an anchor tag; an anchor is an inline element and h2 is a block-level element.

Comment: You might want to consult the HTML5 spec for `a` elements again: "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)." http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-a-element.html#the-a-element

Comment: I guess I was thrown off by the W3C itself! The W3C validator is flagging it as incorrect (in XHTML 1.0 strict): `document type does not allow element "h2" here [...] One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").` http://validator.w3.org

Comment: @TheZ: It has traditionally been disallowed; it was only made valid as of HTML5 due to the change in semantics. It still remains disallowed in HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0.

Comment: "You should not nest an h2 tag inside of an anchor tag; an anchor is an inline element and h2 is a block-level element."
**isn't the h2 tag outside the anchor tag? It comes after the </a>?

Comment: Can I ask what would be the best way to write the html here? I'm still learning and some suggestions would be great. I am checking out all the links you gave me too. Thanks!